# Translation of “early-bird ticket”

Tags: traduction, anglais

An “*early-bird ticket*” is a ticket purchased far in advance. How would you say “*early-bird ticket*” in French?

My ideas:

- [ticket/billet anticipé](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=early%20bird%20ticket)
- ticket/billet acheté en avance
- [ticket/billet pour les lève-tôts](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/early%20bird)

Comment: J'ai lu *billets en vente anticipée* récemment. Mais je ne sais pas exactement ce que c'est :-)

Comment: *Lève-tôt* definitely won't work. That refers only to waking up early.

Comment: I am not sure what an early bird ticket is but maybe I can extrapolate from an early bird dinner. An early bird dinner is served before normal restaurant dinner hours. It costs less and happens when the restaurant is less crowded.

Answer (score 8):

“Prévente” or “pré-vente” would be appropriate

See  [wikitionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pr%C3%A9vente)

Answer (score 2):

As said in Antzi's answer, *Prévente* or *Pré-vente* are good.

I would prefer when possible *Pré-réservation* ("Pre-booking"), a booking being most of the time nothing else than a sale in advance.

*Réservation à l´avance* is also usual.

For purchases one could use *Pré-commande*.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen and been to multiple conferences in France offering early bird tickets. None of them bothered to translate the word in their French descriptions.

As far as I know, there is no strict equivalent. A *ticket en pré-vente* or *pré-réservation* doesn't really convey the fact that it's purchased months and months in advance, possibly without even knowing the programme of the conference or event. And to me, *pré-vente* is generally meant as opposed to *sur place* (on location).

Comment: On emploie encore très peu l'expression billet earlybird en France (ça reste restreint à certains milieux,festivals de musique, etc.). Disons qu'on l'emploie beaucoup moins qu'en allemand par exemple. Par contre je ne suis pas d'accord avec toi sur le sens de prévente. La prévente ne s'oppose pas à l'achat sur place mais à l'achat avant la disponibilité physique du billet, avant la mise sur le marché. Voir définition [ici par exemple](http://www.e-marketing.fr/Definitions-Glossaire-Marketing/Prevente-6063.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Le terme **(L')achat précoce** est peut-être plutôt pour [réserver un produit ou service en avance](http://www.averna.com/fr/nouvelles-evenements-fr/details-nouvelle/averna-to-announce-a-docsis-3.1-early-adopter-program-at-scte-cable-tec-exp) pour assurer de l’avoir quand on veut, mais on peut aussi en profiter pour [avoir les tarifs plus abordables](http://www.airserbia.com/fr/nouvelles/tarifs-plus-abordables-pour-l-achat-precoce).

(C'était pas votre question, mais pour *early-bird special(s)* en general, j'ai vu [*Les [bonnes] affaires précoces*](http://www.nordeclair.fr/Actualite/2011/01/04/soldes-d-hiver-affaires-precoces-a-faire.shtml) et, surtout pour le restauration (et suivant votre idée de *lève-tôt*), j'ai trouvé *[Spécial lève-tôt](http://www.tuttifruttidejeuners.com/fr/menu.php?c=2)* et *[Menu lève-tôt](http://www.eggsquis.com/fr/menu-leve-tot.php)*.)